# The property 'Child.Parent' is of type 'Parent' which is not supported by the current database provider

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I've looked through the similar questions but not been able to find anything that applies to my situation.

I have a `Parent` table with the following property.

```cs
public virtual List<Child> Children { get; set; } = new();
```

And a `Child` class with a link back

```cs
public virtual Parent Parent { get; set; }
```

But when I try to add a migration, I get the error

> The property 'Child.Parent' is of type 'Parent' which is not supported by the current database provider

If I add the following to my `ApplicationDbContext.OnModelCreating`

```cs
builder.Entity<Parent>(x =>
{
  x.HasMany(p => p.Children).WithOne(c => c.Parent);
}
```

Then I get the error

> 'Parent' cannot be used as a property on entity type 'Child' because it is configured as a navigation.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Share your DbContext pls

Comment: Hi @ErikEJ - It just has two public DbSet properties with get/set on them.  If I try to `add builder.Entity<Parent>(x => x.HasMany(p => p.Children).WithOne(c => c.Parent))` then it tells me I cannot add `Children` as a property because it's already being used as a navigation.

Answer (score 0):

I whittled my app down to the bare essentials needed to cause this problem and realised the problem was that I was trying to create a unique index using a navigation property

```cs
builder.Entity<Child>(x =>
{
  x.HasIndex(x => new { x.Parent, x.SomethingElse }).IsUnique();
});
```

Once this was removed the problem no longer occurred.  It seems I cannot use `HasIndex` nor `HasAlternateKey` on a navigation property.

I've reported this as a bug for the behaviour, and a request to make the error message easier to understand https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/28695